# OpsHub - User Mapping Screen throws error after long wait

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Trying an OpsHub migration on TFS2013.3 to VSO, the utility fails on the User Mapping screen before any data can be shown.  The screen's white areas stay blank and eventually after about 5 minutes, and error is thrown via an alert box.

**OpsHub Version:** Latest - downloaded and installed today, 1/23/2015.

**The contents of my OSVMU.log file show this:**

2015-01-23 14:00:41,442 [1] ERROR com.opshub.eai.metadata.MetadataException: OpsHub-014371: Could not instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source 1422039041211 ALM TFS 1422039041213, due to ; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: com.opshub.eai.metadata.MetadataException: OpsHub-014371: Could not instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source 1422039041211 ALM TFS 1422039041213, due to ; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at TFSMigrationUI.ViewModel.UserMappingViewModel.worker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in e:\OVSMUBranch\TFSMigrationUI\ViewModel\UserMappingViewModel.cs:line 416
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how or why, but I deleted the VSO server registration using Visual Studio, and re-added it back via Visual Studio, and this seemed to correct the ObsHub Utility, because now it correctly pulls in all the users / mappings.

Comment: Yes. Steve, the issue was that your VSO end point needed credentials to login in the utility. But the pop-up was not being shown since it was the bg service which was expecting the login. When you did the re-registration of the end point in Visual Studio. On the next run the utility found the end point already authenticated and thus now works correctly.