# TFS to VSO migration with OpsHub hangs on User Mapping

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm attempting to do a migration from TFS on premises to VSO.  I'm using the free OpsHub utility.

I choose the two servers, and the team project, all good.. It gets to the step of User Mapping, and it just hangs there.  The little blue line across the top of the app keeps on cycling across the screen to indicate that it's "working" but it never ever comes back.

What is causing this? is there a log file somewhere I can read that will give me some insight in to what's happening?

Comment: 1). Please go to folder C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs to see whether you can find any error message. Or you can zip the folder and upload it to onedrive, then post here the link. 2). Another community member got the similar issue, and he resolved it via "deleting the VSO server registration using Visual Studio, and re-adding it back via Visual Studio". Please check this link for the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116990/opshub-user-mapping-screen-throws-error-after-long-wait

Comment: I Tried resetting the registration of both servers but no change.the OpsHub log file shows this error:    09/24/2015 12:21:41,677 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl) - OpsHub-014371: Could not instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source 1443105252296 ALM TFS 1443105252298, due to ; nested exception is: 
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the logs from **C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs\OVSMU.log**.

But mostly likely this is an issue of TFS Local Cache. Close all instances of Visual Studio. Close the OVSMU tool. Clear all the contents of the following folders:

*%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache*

*%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache*

*%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache*

Now open the OVSMU tool again, and try to create a new migration.

Comment: Cleared the cache, but still no change.. still hangs on the Map user screen. There was one error from a couple days ago in the OVSMU log file, but no newer entries.  That error was :      ERROR TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server tfs.polarissolutions.com\Default Collection.
Technical information (for administrator):

Comment: Is your machine behind a proxy?